# adding custom colors to Vscode

Tags: vscode-extensions, visual-studio-code

hello i recently switched from Atom to Vs-code and tried some of the tutorials that explain on how to add Language Support on theyre website i understand that language support supposed to have colorizer in it

the question is how do i add colors to custom languages? im used to my own colors when i work on basically every language i have a chill faded look so it wont hurt my eyes

and i created a CSS language support after i tried it out i saw that there was no colors in it but for some reason in the VScode setting [css]: {} got added but it was empty

can someone guide me to what i should do next or how to add colors i couldnt find any information in VScode docs or the internet

EDIT: i created an empty language support without importing textmate file using yo generator.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to customize specific color or other stuff ***basing on a existing color theme***, then 
open *command palette* > *developer:generate color theme from current settings*.

Choose wanted entity and write it in **scope** and **settings**
as in the example beneath. (I looked for customizing **Class color** because in the theme "Monokai Dimmed",imo class color there is awful)

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "textMateRules": [{
        "scope": "entity.name.class, entity.name.type", 
        "settings": {
            "foreground": "#A6E22E"
         }
    }]
}
```

That's similar to the previous answer

Answer (score 2):

Something like this might be useful:

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes#_customizing-a-color-theme

It lets you customize colors via your user settings, e.g. the following would change the color of property names in JSON files:

```
{
  "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "textMateRules": [
      {
        "scope": "support.type.property-name.json",
        "settings": {
          "foreground": "#ff0000"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the way I found to completely customize colors. In your `settings.json`, for texample for black background and very reeddish errors:

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {

    // general settings - will apply to all color themes:
    "editorError.border": "#ff0000",
    "editor.background": "#000000",

    // you can customize for a single theme (fpr example, for dark themes)
    "[dark]": {
        "editor.background": "#000000",
        "terminal.background": "#000000",
        "editorError.foreground": "#ff1144",
        "errorForeground": "#ff1144",
    },
},
```

Settings will autocomplete properties, but just in case you can see the whole list of colors with "Generate color theme from current settings" command.